# Active directory - Powershell 90 days with filter

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, export, days

I have got some code to export all accounts from a particular location in Active directory that haven't been logged into for 90 days and export them to a spreadsheet.

We have some accounts that are for people who are on extended leave so we don't want to list these accounts. Previously we filtered these out using a filter that utilized the 'comment' attribute where by when there was an 'el' in there it ignores these.

Can you advise how I would add this filter to the following code.

```
$Date=get-date    
$Days=90
$DIR='TEST.test.uk/TEST/Users & Desktops/NormalUsers'

Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $DIR -sizeLimit 0 | where {
$_.lastlogontimestamp -and
(($Date-$_.lastlogontimestamp).days -gt $Days) 
} | Select-Object logonName, DisplayName, Comment | export-csv users90.csv
```

I have tried adding `$_.comment -ne "el" -and` to the where but that didnt work.

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean description field? Also if "el" is just a prefix you could use `-notlike "el*"` Dont have the Quest cmdlets but they might not return comment by default. In `Get-ADUSer`  you would need to specify properties outside the default like `Get-aduser -Properties Comment`

Comment: No, not description, within the attributes editor tab in an ad record there is one called 'comment' it is like this due to an old system and thus have to use it instead of description.

Comment: That's fine. I just have never seen anyone use it before so I wanted to clarify. I think you need to use `-IncludeProperties Comment` for your cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter on what is not present. `$_.Comment` is most likely null since it is not included in the default property set of Get-QADUser. From what I can see from the [Documentation](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADUser) is that you need to use `-IncludedProperties Comment`

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $DIR -sizeLimit 0 -IncludedProperties Comment
```

Now your `Where-Object` clause should work as intended. Not sure about the rest of the properties you are calling for but you can always check the default list with `Get-QADPSSnapinSettings`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, how could I miss something so simple as an include. Cheers for fast response.

Comment: @Glad I could help. You could consider marking the answer as accepted to help the community.